# How do I change the initial word command?

Tags: tikz-pgf

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {automata,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[initial,state,accepting] (q0){$q_0$};
\node[state] (q1) [right = of q0] {$q_1$};
\path[->] (q0) edge node[above] {$1$} (q1);         
\end{tikzpicture}
\par\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I want to change the word "start" of `q_0` to another word, it is possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Please remember that you are much more likely to get help if you provide a full but minimal self contained example that others can just copy and test as is. Here you present a sniplet so others have to add a lot of stuff just to be able to test your code.

Comment: I fix it! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `initial  text` key:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {automata,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[initial text=your text]
\node[initial,state,accepting] (q0){$q_0$};
\node[state] (q1) [right = of q0] {$q_1$};
\path[->] (q0) edge node[above] {$1$} (q1);         
\end{tikzpicture}
\par\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! But if I want to do it global? (for the whole document, and not only for this Tikz picture)

Comment: To globally change the `initial text`, you can use `\tikzset{initial text=your text}` in the preamble of your document.

Comment: Thank you!! :-)